# How to make show route display applicant name in node.js/mongoDB app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a website that accepts applications. On the admin panel I wont to display all the applicants and allow a user to click the name to show more info. My issue is the applicant that appears on the show route is always the same no matter who you choose. How can i fix this?

Here is my show route:

```
app.get("/admin/:id", function(req, res){
    Applicant.findOne({}, function(err, foundApplicant) {
        if(err) {
            res.redirect('/admin');
        } else {
            res.render("show", {applicant: foundApplicant});
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass the id to the database

```
app.get("/admin/:id", function(req, res){
    Applicant.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, foundApplicant) {
        if(err) {
            res.redirect('/admin');
        } else {
            res.render("show", {applicant: foundApplicant});
        }
    })
```